# Use \setupinterlinespace for smalls fonts in ConTeXt

Tags: context

What is the correct way to use \setupinterlinespace in ConTeXt?. As you can see, the command doesn't works for small fonts.
Thanks in advance.

```
\starttext
{%
\tf
\setupinterlinespace
This is the long long title of my book\crlf
baselineskip=\the\baselineskip\crlf
}
\blank
{%
\tfa
\setupinterlinespace
This is the long long title of my book\crlf
baselineskip=\the\baselineskip\crlf
}
\blank
{%
\tfb
\setupinterlinespace
This is the long long title of my book\crlf
baselineskip=\the\baselineskip\crlf
}
\blank
{%
\tfc
\setupinterlinespace
This is the long long title of my book\crlf
baselineskip=\the\baselineskip\crlf
}
\blank
{%
\tfd
\setupinterlinespace
This is the long long title of my book\crlf
baselineskip=\the\baselineskip\crlf
}
\blank
{%
\tfxx
\setupinterlinespace
This is the long long title of my book\crlf
baselineskip=\the\baselineskip
}
\stoptext
```

Comment: Just a guess:  Use `\par` instead of `\crlf`.  I don't know the underlying principles, but `\crlf` might force a line break by inserting a large negative penalty, whereas TeX needs a whole paragraph (delimited by `\par` or empty line) to apply things like `\baselineskip`.

Comment: You need to end a paragraph (either by two empty lines or by adding `\par` or `\endgraf`) for line space correction to kick in.

Comment: What can I see? This looks completely fine to me? Please elaborate on your issue.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is not really ConTeXt-specific.  TeX itself operates on whole paragraphs when applying things like `\baselineskip`.  You have to end the paragraph within the curly braces.  You can do so by moving the `\blank` inside the braces (and add a `\blank` in the last one).

```
\starttext
{%
  \tf
  \setupinterlinespace
  This is the long long title of my book\crlf
  baselineskip=\the\baselineskip\crlf
  \blank
}
{%
  \tfa
  \setupinterlinespace
  This is the long long title of my book\crlf
  baselineskip=\the\baselineskip\crlf
  \blank
}
{%
  \tfb
  \setupinterlinespace
  This is the long long title of my book\crlf
  baselineskip=\the\baselineskip\crlf
  \blank
}
{%
  \tfc
  \setupinterlinespace
  This is the long long title of my book\crlf
  baselineskip=\the\baselineskip\crlf
  \blank
}
{%
  \tfd
  \setupinterlinespace
  This is the long long title of my book\crlf
  baselineskip=\the\baselineskip\crlf
  \blank
}
{%
  \tfxx
  \setupinterlinespace
  This is the long long title of my book\crlf
  baselineskip=\the\baselineskip
  \blank
}
\stoptext
```